# Meaning of "p-adic fields" in Jacques Tits' article on classification of semisimple groups

Tags: notation, algebraic-groups

In Jacques Tits' article "Classification of Algebraic Semisimple Groups", which appears in "Algebraic Groups and Discontinuous Subgroups: Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics, Volume IX", when on p. 54 he defines the notation $\mathfrak{p}$ to refer to $\mathfrak{p}$-adic fields, does this mean non-archimedean local fields in characteristic zero or non-archimedean local fields in arbitrary characteristic?

On p. 54 he says "$\textbf{F}$ means "finite fields", $\textbf{R}$ "the field of real numbers", $\mathfrak{p}$ "$\mathfrak{p}$-adic fields" ..." and on p. 47 he says "Let $k$ be the field of $\mathfrak{p}$-adic numbers (for some $\mathfrak{p}$)", which suggests he is talking about the characteristic zero case, I guess. No definition of "$\mathfrak{p}$-adic fields" is given anywhere in the text.

Comment: Well, how does he define it?

Comment: On p. 54 he says "$\textbf{F}$ means "finite fields", $\textbf{R}$ "the field of real numbers", $\mathfrak{p}$ "$\mathfrak{p}$-adic fields" ..." and on p. 47 he says "Let $k$ be the field of $\mathfrak{p}$-adic numbers (for some $\mathfrak{p}$)", which suggests he is talking about the characteristic zero case, I guess. No definition of "$\mathfrak{p}$-adic fields" is given anywhere in the text.

Comment: Put it in the question - answerers should not have to read comments to understand the question. @Rupert